# Apache on localhost: give virtual hosts specific servers name

Tags: apache, localhost, virtualhost

Ok, I ask my question first and below are details of what I have so far trying to solve the thing:

On Apache running on localhost, I want to have different virtual hosts that would be accessible through url:
http://name-of-the-virtual-host.name-of-the-machine/

Details:

So I have Apache running on port 8080 of my laptop. Linux Mint, so Debian distro. Everything is in local for testing purposes, so no DNS involved! The IP address I use is 127.0.1.1 which has the domain of my computer, called fabjoa. On the file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, I've put:

```
ServerName fabjoa
```

In the file `/etc/hosts`, there is indeed the line

```
127.0.1.1   fabjoa
```

In the file `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
Listen 8080
```

Now, the conf file of my virtual host. The file is called is goyahkla and is located on `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` and has a symbolic link in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. On this file, I have the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName goyakhla.fabjoa
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/sites/goyahkla

....

<Directory /var/sites/goyahkla/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

...

</VirtualHost>
```

Running `apache2ctl configtest` gives me Syntax OK. Now, on browser, opening `http://fabjoa:8080/` does point to the Virtual Host goyahkla (beacause that's the only one I have), but `http://goyahkla.fabjoa:8080` is not found. Other debugging:

```
telnet goyahkla.fabjoa:8080
telnet: could not resolve goyahkla.fabjoa:8080/telnet: Name or service not known

lynx goyahkla.fabjoa:8080
Looking up  'goyahkla.fabjoa' first
Looking up  'www.goyahkla.fabjoa.com', guessing...

Looking up goyahkla.fabjoa first
Looking up www.goyahkla.fabjoa.com, guessing...
Looking up www.goyahkla.fabjoa.com:8080
Making HTTP connection to www.goyahkla.fabjoa.com:8080
Alert!: Unable to connect to remote host.

lynx: Can't access startfile http://www.goyahkla.fabjoa.com:8080/
```

Any idea on how purpose could be achieved?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you need to specify full hostname un hosts file? Like "goyahkla.fabjoa" instead of "fabjoa"?

Anyway, this is not programming question and should be asked on serverfault.com

Comment: Ok, i've moved it to server fault